# Layer Swipe slider but with two different maps (components & React)

Tags: reactjs, maps, swipe

Does anyone know how to implement layer swipe slider like this: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/layer-swipe.html
but with two different maps in React?

I tried using react-split-pane but it's giving more of a slider window animation rather than layer swipe. If it's possible to make similar animation using react-split-pane that could also work.

In short, I would like to achieve this effect but with two different map components.

[picture[1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NovcM.jpg)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.